# What's the under-the-hood mechanism g++ uses to identify modification of 'const' variables?

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, g++

when we declare a variable to be const

```
const int cv  = 3;
```

I guess g++ reserve 4 bytes somewhere (say, address 0xFF77 ) in the data area. In the future, when people access cv, the compiler goes to 0xFF77 to get the value 3.

However, how does the compiler store the information 'const'? g++ must somehow store this information, so when another line tries to modify cv, the compiler knows 'oh, this is not correct, because I know 0xFF77 is const'.

Anybody here familiar with gcc compiler?  could you give me some insight?

Thanks

Comment: For global variables the information `const` could be expressed by putting the `int` value in the `.text` section of the executable which is read-only. Other ways are possible.

Answer (score 0):

Once the program is executing, the compiler is no longer present. It's work is done; the program has been compiled into an executable, and it can then be executed without the compiler even being installed. (Consequently, it is possible to distribute executables to machines which have no compiler.)

But even if your question were rewritten to fix that issue, there is an unwarranted and incorrect assumption:

> g++ must somehow store this information, so when another line tries to modify `cv`, the **run-time** knows 'oh, this is not correct, because I know 0xFF77 is const'.

In fact, the run-time is under no obligation to stop the variable from being modified. That is the programmer's responsibility. When you declare a variable to be `const`, you are informing the compiler that you will not modify its value, which may allow the compiler to do a better job of optimising. Such optimisations may fail if it turns out that you do, in fact, modify the variable; that is covered by the fact that modifying a value declared `const` is "undefined behaviour". (Undefined behaviour is really undefined. Throwing an error would be defined behaviour.)

Under certain circumstances, the compiler can in fact detect during compilation that a variable declared `const` is being modified.

```
const int cv = 3;
cv = 42;
```

Most compilers will produce a warning if they see a blatant violation of the contract. But it is a warning, not an error, and there are times when the  compiler has been misled. For example, the following code cannot produce an error, assuming that the function `always_false` lives up to its name:

```
const int cv = 3;
if (always_false(cv)) cv = 42;
```

In short, C++ does not undertake to save you from your errors; if you choose to write programs in C++, you must be prepared to ensure that you play by the rules.

Answer (score 0):

> However, how does the compiler store the information 'const'?

It doesn't. The `const` keyword is a type qualifier. Such knowledge about constness matters during type checking, a task performed by a compiler's frontend.

If no (invalid) attempt to modify a `const` value - beware of the difference between copy and reference/pointer semantics - is found, the compiler's backend will emit code. Then, the data in question is placed in an object file (not necessarily at a read-only section) like ELF.

Eventually, your operating system will load such binary file. What exactly happens upon modification of that once "const object", either from a violating expression not caught by the compiler's type-checker or any intrusive mechanism, can vary.